# Air purifier/humidifier - strange yellow substance

Tags: humidifier, air-quality, air-filter

I have had this [Sharp air purifier/humidifier](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1678714/Sharp-Kc-G60eu.html) for the past 6 months. After cleaning the humidifying filter today I have noticed a strange yellow slimy substance on the filter "fins".

[image]

[image]

I have cleaned the filter using water with lemon juice, as recommended in [its manual](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1678714/Sharp-Kc-G60eu.html?page=15).

I have tried to clean the substance with water, using my fingers, but it is quite sticky and it won't go away.

I have also noticed some yellow deposits in the humidifying tray the past few times I have refilled the water tank. I'm using tap water for it.

What is that yellow substance? Should I be worried about it?

Comment: It looks like pollen that's gotten moist. Not sure though.   Are you in an area with a high pollen count?

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson Not really, I live in an apartment on the seventh floor. I have only used the purifier inside.

Comment: Looks like mildew or other fungus.

Comment: It's mold. You're not supposed to use tap water, right? Wash it in a mild bleach solution to remove. You can treat the water with a tiny amount of boric acid (bug powder), which is a very powerful anti-fungal agent.

Comment: @dandavis Thanks, I've managed to clean it using bleach. 

The manual specifies [tap water](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1678714/Sharp-Kc-G60eu.html?page=9), so it should technically be fine. You are suggesting to add boric acid in the water when I refill the tank, right? 

I'm also drinking filtered tap water, but now I'm not sure if that's safe. Are there any tests that I can do to check if the water is safe of drinking? 

Also, please add this as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Tap water in any municipal system should usually be safe to drink, especially when filtered. If you are concerned, there are a number of services which will test a sample of your tap water for you. The mold is not caused by tap water *per se*, but rather by the combination of dust, which feeds the mold, and a damp environment (it is a humidifier, after all) - even distilled water will grow stuff in this sort of situation! Cleaning with disinfectant or adding disinfectant to the tank should be all that's required to keep it looking clean.

Comment: yes, add a tiny amount of boric acid when refilling, maybe every-other refill as needed to prevent fungal growth. It's powerful yet non-toxic (to vertebrates) and not very corrosive. I don't have a scientific amount in mind, tiny; about as much as would pile up on the head of a small flat-head screwdriver like used for eyeglasses. You could also likewise use a few drops of bleach, or an ounce of H2O2 for prevention; downside to those being potential pool odor and cost respectively. borax is cheap; a $4usd bottle will treat 1000s of refills.

Comment: @dandavis  Sounds like you got this.  It would be helpful if  you could combine your comments into an "answer" since you identified and solved the OPs question.

Comment: It's not mold. I live in Texas an get it in my water air purifier.it look's identical.. Its sticky an smells chemically in my water bowl. Its so bad here it stopped my inlet up an dried to a powder. Once its dry a small breeze will wift it away. It burns your eyes. At night turn you a small flash light on in the dark you can see it everywhere. Looks like smoke but its yellow in water. Looks like some people ate right about something in the air..